# How to create an object of one class with arguments of another? Java

Tags: java, date

I'm creating a user defined classed named "Employee" and it will hold basic data about employees. Such as name, birthday and hire date.

In my previous program I created a user defined class named "Date" this held 3 int values (month, day, year).

Birthday and hire date of the Employee class must be of Date type.

Here is my constructor for my Date class 
 //day, month, year were initialized before

```
 public Date(int m, int d, int y){
     day = d;
     month = m;
     year = y;
 }
```

And an example of instantiating a Date object

```
Date date1 = new Date(1, 1, 1582);
```

Here is my constructor for my Employee class

```
 public Employee(String fName, String lName, Date d1, Date d2) {
   firstName = fName;
   lastName = lName;
   date1 = d1;
   date2 = d2; 
 }
```

When trying to create an object of the Employee class(in another class, this class is named "Employee Test") I get an erorr

> "required:String, String, Date,Date
>
> found: String, String, int, int, int, int, int, int".

```
 Employee e = new Employee("Tom" , "Doe",1 , 5 , 1995, 1 , 6 , 2011 );
```

The issue appears to be that the object is receiving the data as int values rather than type Date, even though the Date objects require 3 int values itself.

I'm confused on how to create this object, is my constructor wrong? Do I need to pass actual instantiated objects as arguments while creating an Employee Object?

Thanks

Comment: please correct you code snippet/ You are declaring Date objects using date1 and Date2 which are undeclared classes. Use Date instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass a Date object! Take a look at this sample:

```
Date date1 = new Date(1, 5, 1995);
Date date1 = new Date(1, 6, 2011);
Employee e = new Employee("Tom" , "Doe",date1, date2 );
```

Now you are passing the two references of a Date object to the Employee constructor. You could even do this:

```
Employee e = new Employee("Tom" , "Doe", new Date(1, 5, 1995), new Date(1, 6, 2011));
```

Comment: You might add another constructor that takes the `m, d, y` arguments directly and calls the existing one in order to answer the question in the title.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by BrunoDM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40580616/642706) is correct and should be accepted.

## Alternate constructors

Here's additional code, as suggested in the comment by schwobaseggl to show an alternate constructor taking arguments that are passed to another constructor of the date class.

Do not name your own class with the name found in the classes bundled with Java. So I use the name `MiniDate` rather than `Date` to avoid confusion with `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`. By the way, in real work, *never* roll-your-own date-time classes such as the date-value seen in your Question. Instead use the java.time classes bundled with Java. In this code we would use `LocalDate` rather than our own `MiniDate` class.

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/h0JeGI).

Here is the `main` method showing each of the two different constructors for `Employee`. In the first we pass instances of `MiniDate`. In the second we pass the year-month-day integer numbers to the constructor of `Employee` which in turns passes them to the constructor of `MiniDate`.

The [late-binding features of Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding#Late_binding_in_Java) automatically determine which constructor actually gets called based on the number and data-types of the arguments.

By the way, in real work, passing the individual components of year-month-day through one constructor to another would likely be a poor idea, clumsy and confusing. Java lacks the [argument labels](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#argument-labels) that work so well in [Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) and [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)) to identify a long series of arguments. So here it would be better to instantiate the `MiniDate` (or better, `LocalDate`) first and then pass the finished objects to the constructor to decrease the number arguments overall.

```
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        MiniDate birthDate = new MiniDate( 1967 , 1 , 23 );
        MiniDate hireDate = new MiniDate( 2016 , 2 , 28 );
        Employee e1 = new Employee( "Wendy" , "Melvoin" , birthDate , hireDate );
        System.out.println( e1 );

        Employee e2 = new Employee( "Lisa" , "Coleman" , 1968 , 2 , 24 , 2016 , 4 , 14 );
        System.out.println( e2 );
    }
}
```

Here we see those constructors, one taking arguments of type `MiniDate` and the other taking arguments of `int` literals.

```
class Employee {
    private String firstName , lastName ;
    private MiniDate birthDate , hireDate ;

    // Constructor
    public Employee( String firstNameArg , String lastNameArg , MiniDate birthDateArg , MiniDate hireDateArg ) {
        this.firstName = firstNameArg;
        this.lastName = lastNameArg;
        this.birthDate = birthDateArg;
        this.hireDate = hireDateArg;
    }

    // Constructor
    public Employee( String firstNameArg , String lastNameArg , int birthYearArg , int birthMonthArg , int birthDayOfMonthArg , int hireYearArg , int hireMonthArg , int hireDayOfMonthArg  ) {
        this.firstName = firstNameArg;
        this.lastName = lastNameArg;
        this.birthDate = new MiniDate( birthYearArg , birthMonthArg , birthDayOfMonthArg );
        this.hireDate = new MiniDate( hireYearArg , hireMonthArg , hireDayOfMonthArg );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "Employee{ name: " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " | birthDate: " + this.birthDate + " | hireDate: " + hireDate + " }" ;
        return s;
    }
}
```

Here is the source code for `MiniDate`. Note again that in real work, you would use [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) rather than your own class, such as `LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.of( 1967 , 1 , 23 ) ;`.

Note that I consistently order the date parts as year-month-day. This follows the style of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. I strongly suggest you use the formats and style of this standard in your date-time work.

```
class MiniDate {
    // For teaching purposes only. In real work, use `LocalDate` class bundled with Java.
    private int year , month , dayOfMonth ;

    public MiniDate( int yearArg , int monthArg , int dayOfMonthArg ) {
        this.year = yearArg;
        this.month = monthArg;
        this.dayOfMonth = dayOfMonthArg;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // Generate string in standard ISO 8601 format, padding with zeros as needed.
        String s = this.year + "-" + String.format( "%02d", this.month ) + "-" + String.format( "%02d", this.dayOfMonth ) ;
        return s ;
    }
}
```

Comment: 6 consecutive int parameters might be too many for the user to remember. Sticking to ISO-8601 certainly helps.

Comment: @LukeLee I never said the year-month-day arguments were a good idea! I said I was following the suggestion that we **more directly answer the Question as posed** which involves creating “an object of one class with arguments of another”.

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt want to create your dates before you can also build them in the call:

```
Employee e = new Employee("Jane", "Doe", new Date(1, 4, 1993), new Date(2, 4, 1993);
```